# How can I leverage the msbuild 15 NuGet functionality to push the created package to my own NuGet repository?

Tags: msbuild, nuget

I use msbuild 15 to create the nuget package with the `pack` target. Great, but now I want to push the package to my NuGet repository.

I do not want to assume nuget.exe exists on the build machine and I do not want to write code to download it - I have it from my older projects, but I do not feel it is right to use both msbuild and nuget.

And since my NuGet repo is just a shared folder I can always just copy the file over.

But I am curious if msbuild provides the functionality of `nuget push`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MSBuild does not have the functionality, but if your build machines have the dotnet cli installed, you can use `dotnet nuget push`.